# Builder Pattern : Separation of construction from representation

Tags: design-patterns, builder-pattern

I am reading GoF, and the intent of builder is mentioned as to separate creation of complex object from its representation.

**I couldn't understand what representation means in this context.
What does it mean?**

The Text parsing example provided in the motivation section doesn't seem to separate construction from representation, but algorithm for interpretation of textual format from creation and representation of converted format.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The representation of interest is here the (presumably) string result obtained from `GetASCIIText` or `GetTexText`.

Someone has to create an instance of the abstract `TextConverter`; this is not shown within the diagram you posted in the question.

Some code somewhere chooses between one of the three sub classes to instantiate and then supplies that to the `RTFReader`.

This might look as follows:

```
var tx = new TexConverter ();
var rdr = new RTFReader ( tx );
rdr.ParseRTF ();
return tx.GetTexText ();
```

and, in another case,

```
var cv = new ASCIIConverter ();
var rdr = new RTFReader ( cv );
rdr.ParseRTF ();
return cv.GetASCIIText ();
```

With this additional context, we can see more clearly the separation of construction responsibilities from representation responsibilities, as `ParseRTF` is reused unchanged between these two snippets even though each snippet generates a different representation.

Further, if we wanted to, we could create an implementation for `TextConverter` that wrapped the other three and created all those representations with one call to `ParseRTF`.  This would not be as easy to do if these responsibilities were not separated.

It should be pointed out that in this example, the resulting data structures that are constructed do not necessarily have to conform to each other, so, `GetTexText`, could, if desired, return a type different from string and different from `GetASCIIText`; this would illustrate vastly different representations.

Comment: RE : "separation of construction responsibilities " , here in the given example `ParseRTF`, isn't constructing anything(not even parse tree), only interpreting. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: It has the responsibility for the algorithm that directs the construction.  We can consider that it is constructing in the abstract.

Comment: I think, I would have not asked this question if names of function were like like `addCharacter` `addFont`, instead of `convertXXX` in `ParseRTF`, it would have been more intuitive then.

Comment: @ErikEidt could you more succinctly describe what an object's representation is?

Comment: The complex objects they're talking about are the outputs that need to be created by the common algorithm.  The inputs here are RTF files, and the outputs vary in type.  For GetASCIIText could be a simple string; for GetTeXText it could be a string serialization of TeX format, or a collection of TeX objects or a pointer to a root TeX object; for GetTextWidget it could be a set of graphical user interface objects.  So the complex objects are high-level domain concepts possibly compositions of multiple object in the low-level programming environment.

Comment: In some ways this pattern is similar to Strategy pattern, except that with that one, all the strategy implementations must provide the common interface, and there is no latitude for varying return types.  Whereas with this Builder pattern, each concrete builder can have a custom interface for the final action of building the result of interest: there's no need for them all to conform with each other.